# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: update SysUser set deleted = :deleted where id = :id

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

Please help to solve the below error. I have tried below code but i got below mentioned error.

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: update SysUser set deleted = :deleted where id = :id** .

```
Session session = getSession();
boolean deleted=true;
int id=1;

String hqlUpdate = "update SysUser set deleted = :deleted where id = :id";
int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
            .setBoolean( "deleted", deleted )
            .setInteger(id, id)
            .executeUpdate();
session.close();
```

Comment: Did it solve the problem now ?

Comment: Please check my answer. @Sakthi Draggerz

Comment: if so please accept/vote it @SakthiDraggerz

Comment: if so please accept/vote it @SakthiDraggerz

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parameter name `:id` properly for `setInteger` as shown below in your **HQL** query:

```
int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
                    .setBoolean( "deleted", deleted )
                    .setInteger("id", id)
                    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Why does "delete" parameter have not ":" and "id" parameter have ":"?

Comment: I tries as above but i got Exception as  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter :id does not exist as a named parameter in [update SysUser set deleted = :deleted where id = :id] .please help me where i went wrong

Answer (score 1):

replace `id` in `setInteger(id,id)` with `"id"` like `setInteger("id",id)`